# Laravel 8 not running in live server

Tags: laravel-8

After i upgrade laravel 8 from 7, the project not running in live server. both nginx and apache tried. no use. but the application is running well in Wamp or Xampp server on localhost. Then i debug the project showing this error on live server. here is the error i got on live server

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Repositories\Configuration\RoleRepository] does not exist.
Illuminate\Container\Container::build
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:879
```

I checked that the RoleRepository file is exist in project.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example <<<=== that's important. `both nginx and apache tried. no use` <<<=== any error messages? Copy/paste the text of the error message. You said it's on live server. Did you run `composer install` on your live server?